# Tagging questions regarding subjects with long names

Tags: support, tags

How do you tag a question about a namespace (for example, from .NET) whose natural name is longer than the maximum tag length?

My specific example was System.DirectoryServices.Protocols from .NET, but I am sure this is far from the only one.

Comment: I don't know anything about that namespace, but aren't there tags that encompass its concepts that are more general?

Comment: The problem is this:  there is another namespace which is unfortunately a shorter name (System.DirectoryServices) which works completely differently, and you also want to contrast against non .NET directory service or LDAP programming issues from other languages or frameworks.

Comment: Yeah, I was just looking, I see that `System.DirectoryServices` does have a tag.  Not sure what to tell you, then.  I suppose abbreviating it somehow and making a good tag wiki to explain for what situations it should be used might work.  See if anyone who is active in that area chimes in.